# If rank = this put team here?

Tags: php, mysql

How can I do this?

add a number 1 to the field `gameswon` if this occurs:

Pseudocode:

```
table names = 'games', 'teams'
fields =  score1, score2, gameswon

If 'games'.score1 > 'games'.score2
    add 1 to 'teams'.gameswon
else if 'games'.score2 > 'games'.score1
    add 1 to 'teams'.gameswon
```

---

Also:

how can I rank teams from one table who have the same field in another table?

for example:

it has `rank` field in table `'teams'`

and it has `pool1` field in table `'games'`

so if `pool1` is the same in table `'games'` then update `rank` in table `'teams'` --

rank code:

```
if gameswon from TEAM1 > gameswon from TEAM2 and > gameswon from TEAM3
    rank TEAM1 with a 1
```

IS THIS POSSIBLE?

Comment: So, you have one table
`games` with fields `score1` and `score2`, and presumably fields `team1` and `team2` for the two participants
and 
another table `teams` with field `gameswon` (as well as team name etc)?

Comment: (By the way, if you use four spaces at the beginning of a line it puts it into `this font` which is helpful for separating `code` from other text - or use the back-tick character ` to do it in-line)

Answer (score 0):

first question query:

```
INSERT
INTO   teams
       (
          gameswon
       )
SELECT 1 AS gameswon
FROM   games
WHERE  score1 <> score2
```

second question I do not understood 
please provide full table structure